# Having problems causing re-render with boolean variables in my state object

Tags: javascript, redux

So I have a couple boolean variables in my state to control visibility of certain elements in my ui and I try to toggle it by dispatching an action through a button onClick but it doesn't seem to be working...

container component

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleUnexcusedAbsences, toggleUnexcusedTardies, toggleExcused } from '../actions'
import AttendanceDetails from '../components/AttendanceDetails'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('state:', state);
  console.log('state.unexcusedAbsencesShow:', state.unexcusedAbsencesShow);

  return {
    attendance: state.eventsSlipsRolls,
    unexcusedAbsencesToggle: state.unexcusedAbsencesShow,
    unexcusedTardiesToggle: state.unexcusedTardiesShow,
    excusedToggle: state.excusedShow
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onAbsencesToggle: () => {
      dispatch(toggleUnexcusedAbsences())
    },
    onTardiesToggle: () => {
      dispatch(toggleUnexcusedTardies())
    },
    onExcusedToggle: () => {
      dispatch(toggleExcused())
    }
  }
}

const AttendanceBar = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AttendanceDetails)

export default AttendanceBar
```

presentational component

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Button, Collapse, Well } from 'react-bootstrap'

import { joinValidClasses } from '../constants'

const AttendanceDetails = ({ attendance, unexcusedAbsencesToggle, unexcusedTardiesToggle, excusedToggle, 
  onAbsencesToggle, onTardiesToggle, onExcusedToggle }) => {

  console.log('unexcusedAbsencesToggle', unexcusedAbsencesToggle);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={onAbsencesToggle}>
        Unexcused Absences
      </Button>
      <Collapse in={unexcusedAbsencesToggle}>
        <div>
          <Well>
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
            Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
          </Well>
          <Well>
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
            Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
          </Well>
        </div>                                  
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  )
}

AttendanceDetails.propTypes = {
  attendance: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object.isRequired).isRequired,
  unexcusedAbsencesToggle: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  unexcusedTardiesToggle: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  excusedToggle: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  onAbsencesToggle: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onTardiesToggle: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onExcusedToggle: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default AttendanceDetails
```

reducer

```
import { TOGGLE_UNEXCUSED_ABSENCES, TOGGLE_UNEXCUSED_TARDIES, TOGGLE_EXCUSED } from '../actions';
import initialState from '../initialState';

function toggleVisibility(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_UNEXCUSED_ABSENCES:
      let toggle = Boolean(!state.unexcusedAbsencesShow)
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        unexcusedAbsencesShow: toggle
      });
    case TOGGLE_UNEXCUSED_TARDIES:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        unexcusedTardiesShow: !state.unexcusedTardiesShow
      });
    case TOGGLE_EXCUSED:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        excusedShow: !state.excusedShow
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default toggleVisibility;
```

action creators

```
export const toggleUnexcusedAbsences = () => {
  return {type: TOGGLE_UNEXCUSED_ABSENCES};
}

export const toggleUnexcusedTardies = () => {
  return {type: TOGGLE_UNEXCUSED_TARDIES};
}

export const toggleExcused = () => {
  return {type: TOGGLE_EXCUSED};
}
```

Comment: I recommend debugging with redux-logger. It's of great help in solving these sort of problems. https://github.com/fcomb/redux-logger If you're already using it, please post screenshots of the output. Also, the way you rename all your state properties in mapStateToProps just makes the rest of your code difficult to reason about. I suggest not doing that.

Comment: ok I figured it out stupid me, I didn't pass this particular reducer into my store